# Dealing with StringIndexOutOfBoundsException even if the specified field is empty

Tags: android, crash

[image]I'm getting an app crash that happens when I press the Submit button of my android application.
The application deals with sending the entered data to be added as an event in the user's calendar.
The app crashes only when the date field is left empty.
I've noticed that there is a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException for the variables which store the split parts of the date.I tried commenting the date field data input and then the app works.

Why does this exception occur if the said field is left empty?

Any fixes will be appreciated.

Code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        TextInputEditText textInputEditTextDate = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
        EditText editTextTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        EditText editTextDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.desc);
        EditText editTextLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);
        titl = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
        desc = editTextDesc.getText().toString();
        location = editTextLocation.getText().toString();
        date = textInputEditTextDate.getText().toString();
        day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));
        month = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5)) - 1;
        year = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6, 10));

        if (titl.isEmpty() || desc.isEmpty() || location.isEmpty() || date.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
            calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, titl);
            calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
            calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, desc);
            calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_DEFAULT);
            calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 1);
            calendarIntent.putExtra(String.valueOf(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT), "1");
            GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
            calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, date.getTimeInMillis());
            calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, date.getTimeInMillis());
            startActivity(calendarIntent);
        }
    }
```

Logcat:

```
Process: com.cypherlabs.calendarapp, PID: 32057
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7333)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27773)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7333) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299) 
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27773) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445) 
     Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=2
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2032)
        at com.cypherlabs.calendarapp.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7333) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299) 
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27773) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Comment: Does the error indicate that it is caused by this code?
`day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));`

Comment: yes..i'm thinking of putting that part of code in an if clause i.e these variables will be used only if the date field isn't empty would that work?

Comment: Yep, essentially you need to validate all the inputs that you're getting from the text fields.  
e.g.
`if(date != null && !date.isEmpty()){
//rest of the stuff you want to do with date
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as expected. You have done a mistake. The issue is you can not call 
subString() on an empty String. But when your fields are empty, according to code
it will try to call subString() method on null vales.

It can be resolved like below.

```
if(date!=null && !date.isEmpty()){
     day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));
     month = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5)) - 1;
     year = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6, 10));
}
```

Keep in mind to all ways follow these kind of validations in each and every time where an user input is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because of this line:

`day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));`

The second param is bigger than the length of the String, so the `substring` method is throwing the exception.

This is the substring method where you can check why it is throwing the exception:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (beginIndex < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(this, beginIndex);
        }
        if (endIndex > length()) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(this, endIndex);
        }
        int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
        if (subLen < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
        }

        return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == length())) ? this
                : fastSubstring(beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

I would check the length of the `date` String before manipulating it. As your `hint` has the `DD/MM/YYYY` format, you should ensure that the string contains 10 characters.